# Reduced word labeling of Bruhat Order

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-groups, coxeter-groups

For the (strong) Bruhat order on $S_n$, I normally label vertices by permutations in one-line notation and edges by which transposition you multiply by to go up by a cover. I am now trying to better understand the reduced word characterization of the Bruhat order. I know that $u \leq v$ in the Bruhat order if and only if any reduced word for $v$ contains a subword which is a reduced word for $u$.

What I'm wondering is the following: is there a consistent way to label the vertices by reduced words so that every edge corresponds to the removal of one letter? I see a lot of diagrams in papers where intervals in the Bruhat order are labeled in this way but I can not see a way to prove you can label the whole poset like this.

Comment: I believe there is a comment in the book 'Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups' that says that the usual Normal Form (lexicographically least reduced word with respect to some total order of the generating set) is enough to answer this question more generally if we only consider the weak Bruhat Order. Perhaps that is a good place to get some intuition...